# Find the value of following complex number

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If $a= \cos x + i\sin x$ how to get value of $$\frac{(1+a)}{(1-a)}=i \cot \frac x2$$

Comment: Have you tried writing it out (and rationalizing the denominator?)

Comment: Yes, but after few lines I got stucked

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you write out how far you got so that others can help you with the next step.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that final result? I find this quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you write out $\frac{1+a}{1-a}$ and rationalize the denominator (multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator), you will reach
$$
\frac{i\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}.
$$

Next, you need to show that this is equal to
$$
i\cot(x/2)
$$

This can be done with the double angle formulas since $\sin(x)=2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$ and $\cos(x)=1-2\sin^2(x/2)$.

Comment: Yah  same i have done it.But unable to proceed further.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

$$1+a=1+2\cos^2(x/2)-1+2i\sin (x/2) \cos (x/2)=2\cos (x/2)(\cos (x/2)+i\sin (x/2))=$$  $$=2i\cos (x/2)(\sin (x/2)-i\cos (x/2)).$$ $$1-a=1-2\cos^2(x/2)+1-2i\sin (x/2)\cos (x/2)=2-2\cos^2(x/2)-2i\sin (x/2)\cos (x/2)$$ $$=2\sin^2 (x/2)-2i\sin (x/2)\cos (x/2)=2\sin (x/2)(\sin (x/2)-i\cos (x/2)).$$